# Centroid of Triangle problem failing for other test cases

Tags: python, rounding

```
x1=int(input())    #Centroid/Equidistant
y1=int(input())
x2=int(input())
y2=int(input())
x3=int(input())
y3=int(input())
X=(x1+x2+x3)/3
Y=(y1+y2+y3)/3
print(round(X,4))
print(round(Y,5))
```

Sample Input

```
4,
3,
33,
12,
1,
2
```

Sample Output

```
12.6667,
5.66667
```

I am able to get the required output by rounding off X and Y to different decimal places but the program is failing for other test cases. I don't know what those test cases are but my program is not passing for those other test cases. Is there any solution?

Comment: How could be help to "pass unknown tests" ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order for other to effectively help you, please give a clear description of the problem you are facing and be more specific with your question.

Aside from that, just posting your homework code here and hope that others just tell you the solution won't help you learn anything.

Comment: Actually I came across this problem on a website where I had to write the program for the centroid of a triangle. The code is evaluated on the basis of 3 test cases. The first test case is given to  me which provides me with the input and the output I should get after running my code. After I submit my code for evaluation it tests my code on some other test cases which  are not described to me and gets my code wrong for the remaining two test cases.